# Need help in ArcGIS Java Script API : Installation & configuration with different browsers

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

We are using ArcGIS Java Script API (version 3.2, 3.0, 2.8) according to our requirement we are using various API’s.

1. Currently ESRI launched new version 3.3 so if I want to view old examples references i.e version 2.8, 3.0 how do I view the old examples (Because they removed old examples)?
2. Similarly, Can I install multiple SDK( 2.8,3.0,3.2) on single machine? In addition, I need recommended browser settings as if one of my application is not displaying the legend in IE 8.0

Therefore, what are the recommended settings for all versions (2.8 to 3.2)

Any suggestions /discussions will be great !!!

Thanks in advance : )

Comment: What kind of requirements force you to use old APIs? Also, the JavaScript SDKs are just files, not programs, so they aren't "installed", just copied, so you can have however many you want on a single machine.

Comment: @Anthony-GISCOE-  You are correct.. I am using (http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2009/05/29/an-easier-way-to-zoom-a-dojo-dijit-that-zooms-to-states-and-counties/) this tool and its supports 2.8 API because of old dojo/dijit references . I tried to change the code but its getting an error..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Here are the archived versions of the javascript API with all the demos, docs and api. I run the 2.8 version on a local IIS for a couple apps that still use that version. I don't why, but you need to login with Esri Global account to download. Account is free if you don't have one. http://www.esri.com/apps/products/download/index.cfm?fuseaction=download.all#ArcGIS_API_for_JavaScript
2. Anthony is right, you can have multiple versions of the library -- there's no installation. You just reference the new version with any css in your pages. The css has changed lately. Follow the examples for needed references. On your legend, you would need to be more specific. However, one thing to check is the browser and document mode in IE8. If you're running the site on your own network, IE8 will default to compatibility -- which can cause problems.

Comment: thanks for the reply.. I will check this and let you know : )